# Xamarin Forms determine size text will consume

Tags: xamarin.forms, text-size

I believe I have seen this someplace before.  I believe this is a way, based on knowing the text you are going to put in a control (say a label), that you can ask Xamarin Forms to tell you what the size of the control would be.  If I recall correctly you used somaline like OnDevice and had to pass in the Text and the type of control.  I just can't seem to find this now.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

To be clear I am trying to address a defect in a third party control (SyncFusion DataGrid) I am using where the control is not sizing a grid column correctly.  I was trying no to wait until the fix we released but I guess I will have to.

Comment: Is that "Text-Size" is FontSize or Height-Width?

What you are trying to do? Are you trying to autofit the contents of the label by auto adjusting its font-size to fit the contents?
Are you trying to set the Width-Height of the Label by counting Words? 
It is very unclear.
Or you are trying to set FontSize property based on Platform/DeviceType?

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Sorry for the confusion, trying to set the Width-Height of the Label by counting Words.

Comment: Did you tried this https://gist.github.com/alexrainman/82b00160ab32bef9e69dee6d460f44fa

Comment: @NirmalSubedi  I have not tried this as I don't want to have custom code for each platform if possible.  As an example, that code shown does not address MacOS.    There was something I saw that you could run in your PCL - thus the OnDevice that I was looking to find again.  Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: i think the custom render maybe the easiest way to achive this,but you should define for each platform.

Comment: @LeoZhu how would a custom rendered tell me the size that the text is going to consume in say a label control?

Comment: you could calculate on different platform according to your string，refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67545/how-to-calculate-or-measure-width-of-a-string

Comment: Thanks @LeoZhu.  I know I can to it in each device platform but I swear there was a way to do it in the Xamarin Forms class library using something like OnDevice but I can't seem to find info on that now.  Maybe it was removed?

Comment: i can't find the related documents too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncfusion actually posted an updated that does finally seem to fix the problem of the columns not being sized correctly by width.  I can't close this so I will just mark this as the answer.

For Syncfusion you can now do this:

```
mydatagrid.GridColumnSizer.Refresh();
mydatagrid.WidthRequest = mydatagrid.GetVisualContainer().ExtentWidth;
```